# How to push file to my another repository

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a private repository store my code, and run these code on github action everyday.

Recently, I need to create a new public repository to show people my data, lets say 'Kow.csv'

So, I was wondering is there a way to copy this file to this public repository on github action everyday? which mean, I run my code in my private repo and publish my data in my public repo.
Below is the code im using right now, but failed

```
name: test
'on':
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 22 * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  craw_process_bot:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: check_code
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-Python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'
      - name: install requirements
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install pandas
          ...
          pip install pyautogui
      - name: process data
        run: python ./code/global_code/all_process.py
      - name: commit and push if it changed
        run: |
          git config user.name "${GITHUB_ACTOR}"
          git config user.email "${GITHUB_ACTOR}@users.noreply.github.com"
          git add -A
          timestamp=$(date -u)
          git commit -m "Last updated on: ${timestamp}" || exit 0
          git remote add origin https://github.com/###/###.git # address of the public repo
          git push -u origin master
```

the error is:

```
error: remote origin already exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

The default *default remote* repository is `origin`. Therefore, when adding a new repository to a cloned repository in GitHub Actions, you need to use a different name. For the purpose of your action, you could name it `public`.

Here is the part that needs to be changed:

```bash
git remote add public https://github.com/abc/xyz.git # address of the public repo
git push -u public master
```

*Depending on the security settings and ownership, you might need to authenticate with the remote `public`.*

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried with your code, and it got error again. remote: Permission to ###/###.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/###/###.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Process completed with exit code 128. Maybe because the authenticate part u mentioned? sorry im newbee to github:(